# Chain Rule for multivariables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $F(t,k,k')=\exp{(-rt)}.U(w(t)+2k(t)-k'(t))$

We want to calculate the partial derivatives (second and third).

and this is what I found in a book :

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial k}=\frac{\partial (\exp{(-rt)}.U(w(t)+2k(t)-k'(t)))}{\partial k}=2\exp{(-rt)}.U'(w(t)+2k(t)-k'(t))$

But actually this is what I thought of :

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial k}=\exp{(-rt)}\frac{\partial U}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial k}=\frac{2\exp{(-rt)}.U'(w(t)+2k(t)-k'(t))}{k'}$

And I don't know where's my mistake, probably I didn't use well the chain rule in this case.

Comment: The problem: you are considering $k$ *simultaneously* like variable and function. This is confusing in the best case (the book) and nonsensical in the worst (your calculations).

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable questions:

If $U:\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$, we can define the *composite* function
$$(t,p,q,r)\longmapsto\varphi(t,p,q,r) = \exp{(-rt)}U(p + 2q -r),$$
and you can ask by the partial derivatives of this function.

Now, using $w,k:\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ we can define *another* composite function
$$t\longmapsto\varphi(t,w(t),k(t),k'(t)) = \exp{(-rt)}U(w(t) + 2k(t) - k'(t)).$$
The derivative (function of *one* variable!) of this function can be calculated using the chain rule and in the (rather big) expression it will appear the partial derivatives of $\varphi$ (function of *several* variables!).

Comment: that does not answer the question, we do use the chain rule in order to derive the function with respect to other function 'as a variable'. so in my case it makes sense. what i m asking now is to verify my calculus and tell me if it's wrong (and where ) or right. it's that simple

Comment: Concretely: $\partial t/\partial k$ doen't makes **any** sense.

Comment: its $\frac{1}{\frac{\partial k}{\partial t}}=1/k'$

Comment: @Anas, OK, the hideous Leibniz notation attacks again. Doesn't makes sense because $t$ *isn't* a function of $k$. $t$ is a *independent* variable.

Comment: @Anas, and now a incoherence: Why $F(t,k,k′)$ but not $F(t,w,k,k′)$?

Comment: @Anas, $\partial U/\partial t$ isn't nonsensical, but the correct notation is $U'(t)$.

Comment: @Anas, and the $U$ in $F(\cdots)$ isn't $U(t)$ but $U(w(t) + 2k(t) − k′(t))$.

Comment: @Anas, the book is doing *confusely* the following in my notation: the partial derivative of $\varphi$ respect of the (actual third) variable $q$ and evaluating the result on $(t,w(t),k(t),k'(t))$.